# my Xcode Objective-C iOS app crashes when it calls a member in my static lib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My hello world app running on iPad crashes when it calls my static lib.
App does nothing but call member get_string in static lib.

I copied .h & .a to a folder within app's project folder, and added search paths to .h and .a
Builds, runs, then crashes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Send me your code I'll take a look. Here is my email address rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com

Comment: I've built 2 projects using your examples and have no crash (Xcode 12.0.1, iOS 14 simulator).  Can you run the `nm` utility on the library that you've linked to?  Specifically, there should be a line like `0000000000000000 t -[hello_world_lib2 get_string]` in the output.

Comment: When I create the lib, should I select the "Add to" pulldown in the Create window?

Comment: Rahul, I just emailed app and lib to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working.  (iOS feels like a form of malware....when you have to program it.  How programmer indifferent is Xcode compared with Visual Studio.
I remember a few years ago when Xcode rated only 2 stars on the Apple Store itself.)

Anyway, I hope this solution saves others the days of trial-and-error it took me to figure out the magic --- and no Apple dev programming guides or examples for a simple static lib, that I could find.

1. Create static lib project
2. Add functionality.  eg. a member fn that returns a string
3. Build
4. Create objC app
5. Create folder for static lib within app proj folder
6. Copy (ctrl drag) .h & .a from static lib proj lefthand product pane to staticLib folder within app folder
7. Import .a & .h: Drag .a and .h from staticLib folder to app’s lefthand project window, line beneath proj line
8. Copy app > TARGETS > target > Build settings > All > Search Paths > Library Search Paths
   to

> Header Search Paths
> 9.  Set active scheme to target HW (eg. your iPhone or iPad)
> 10. Set PROJECT build settings > Basic > Deployment section > iOS Dep Targ = iOS of target HW (eg. 13.6)
> 11. Verify build ok

Comment: also your lib is not having X86 arch so I wasn't able to test it on simulator

Comment: When I did it, I just set the header and library paths of the settings and added the library to the link library phase, all in the main project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you're calling a class method/ static function on instance.
It should be called like this
NSLog(@"----------------- %@ ------------------------", [[hello_world_lib2 class] get_string]   );
[image: Console Log]

Comment: @Doug Null Tested on real device and my answer is correct. I am able to get the output in console